# retreiving all values of a specified attribute name in a list?

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using selenium java i want to get all the values of a specified attribute within the current page
exemple :

```
<div my_attribute="value1">
<div my_attribute="value2">
<div my_attribute="value3">
```

how i get the result : value1, value2, value3 to store them in a list of strings

Comment: `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[my_attribute]")).stream().map(e -> e.getAttribute("my_attribute").toList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of web elements with attribute `my_attribute` and then iterate over that list to collect all the attribute values.
Something like this:

```java
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@my_attribute]"));
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
for(WebElement el:list){
    String value = el.getAttribute("my_attribute");
    values.add(value);
}
```